# False Negative Search Results in WIndows Server 2008 File Explorer

Tags: windows-server-2008

When I search "Computer" for cdo*.dll, windows says "No items match your search", but if I conduct the same search from C:\Windows\System32, it finds cdosys.dll.

When I look in Search Options, the checkbox "Include subfolders when typing in the Search box" is ticked.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Tick "Include system directories" in Search Options.